# Accessing Web App Files by Cloud Service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-cloud-services

I have deployed my web app and the cloud service on windows azure. Web app saved some of the image files on its own directory lets say on root of the website  there is folder name "Content" and web app save the image files on this folder. is there a way a cloud service can access files inside that folder? cloud service is separate project and hence has its own url and hosted on windows azure portal.

Comment: Hi Hammad, just to clarify do you have two components here - a Web App (aka a Website) and a Cloud Service (aka a Web Role/Worker Role)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, it is not possible to share files stored in a web app with a cloud service. What you should do instead is save the files in `Blob Storage`. That way both Web App and Cloud service can have access to the files.

Comment: +1 for Blob Storage. Web Roles within Cloud Services are non-durable - that means they can be bounced at any time by the Service Fabric, so you shouldn't rely on them for (durable) storage. You might also want to consider Azure Websites, but I would imagine you will still need to use Blob Storage.

Answer (score 0):

Another option you have is Azure File Services, you will have the chance to used as a network shared location.

take a look at this here:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files/